# "Unanswered" question has an answer

Tags: discussion

I was looking at the list of unanswered questions and I found a question on the list that was answered by belisarius. The question I'm referring to is [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11261/how-to-repeat-a-plot-with-different-options). Is this a bug in the SE software? Perhaps a moderator should attend to this.

The question is: How to repeat a plot with different options

Comment: You didn't link to a question... you linked to some page on the unanswered questions list (I don't see anything there). Note that the software will mark a question as "unanswered" if it has no upvoted answers.

Comment: @rm-rf It's one of those virtual answers of mine

Comment: What @rm-rf said about the answer needing at least one upvote is what I needed to know.

Comment: Just upvote my answer and you'll see how the question vanishes from the unanswered list :D

Comment: @belisarius and upvote all my answers for world peace? :D

Comment: @rm-rf Already done. I got a suspension and a letter from SE warning me about voting toads.

Comment: @belisarius I got the same letter, but I think it was a public service announcement: beware of voting toads.